# If-Else State Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to get an if-else statement based on a state value.
My code is set up in a way to change the state whenever and to whatever a `<select>` element is changed to.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
if(this.state{value:} == "string")
{
   //Do this
}
```

However seem to not be able to correctly do this. What might be a better suggestion or the correct way to do this?

Actual code I am trying :

```
  7     this.state = {value: 'empty'};
  8   }
  9   SelectChange = (event) => {
 10     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 11     if(this.state[value] == "string" )
 12     {
 13       console.log("string");
 14     }
 15   }
 16   /*}
 17   AddListener = (event) => {
 18     var id = event.target.id;
 19     var selectElements = document.getElementById(id);
 20     var stringSpec = id.substr(10, 11);
 21     var specLeng = "specifySection" + stringSpec;
 22     //console.log("This Id: " + id + "NumString: |" + stringSpec + "| New Id: "     + specLeng);*/
 23     /*selectElements.addEventListener("change", function(){
 24       moreInfo(id, specLeng);
 25     }, false); */
 26   render (){
 27     const {SelectChange} = this;
 28     const {value} = this.state;
 29     return (
 30       <div>
 31         <div>
 32           <label><strong>New Field </strong></label>
 33           <div id="remove-" className="remove" style={{display: "inline", visibi    lity: "hidden"}}>
 34            <label> --Remove </label> <input type="checkbox" id="removeBox" class    Name="rmvCheckbox" />
 35             <br />
 36           </div>
 37           <label> Name: </label>
 38           <input id="name-" className="name" type="text" name="name" /> <br />
 39           <label> Description: </label>
 40           <input id="description-" className="description" name="description" />     <br />
 41           <label> Datatype: </label>
 42           <select value={value} onChange={SelectChange} id={`selectData-${this.p    rops.number}`} className="selectData" name="selectData" /*onClick={AddListener}*    />
```

Comment: What is the `value`? You can show us the jsx code?

Comment: Check this solution also https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4rj1nk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.setState({})` is a async function. So when you use `this.state.value` in `if` condition right after this function. The value is not set yet. So you can you the value passed from the parameter

```
if(event.target.value === "string")
```

Or you can use a callback function

```
this.setState({value: event.target.value}, () => {
  if(this.state.value === 'string') {
    // Do what you want here
  }
})
```

Comment: isn't it typeof (this.state.value) === 'string' ? this.state.value will be something like 'some value'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(this.state.value == "string"){
 //do this
}
```

option 2

```
this.state.value == "string" ? handleTrue() : handleFalse();
```

option 3 .. if you want to check just true

```
this.state.value && handleTrueLogic();
```

Comment: I did try that, however it did not seem to work. I just tried to output something into the console, and nothing happened

Comment: @alex -> show me your onchange() function whenever you click the select element?

Answer (score 0):

You did a wrong syntax. If the `value` is dynamic. It should be

```
if(this.state[value] == "string")
{
   //Do this
}
```

Comment: gave me "'value' is not defined  no-undef" error when I tried that syntax